# Get best offers from the database query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running this query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.descricao, p_s.preco as antigo, pr.preco as novo
FROM produtos_supermercados p_s
JOIN produtos p
ON(p_s.id_produto = p.id)
JOIN promocoes pr
ON(pr.id_produto = p.id)
```

and I'm getting this results:

```
id  descricao                   antigo          novo
16 Cookies Diet Jasmine         R$3,40        R$1,50
17 Creme de Leite Nestle 300g   R$1,99        R$1,00
48 Johnson Baby Shampoo 200ml   R$4,00        R$2,00
49 Televisão LCD LG             R$999,90      R$2,00
```

I want to get the two best offers, where `antigo` is the normal price and `novo` is the offert price.
So, in this case, I want to run a query that returns `Televisão LCD LG` in the first place, because is the best offer(the original price was $999 ans now it costs only $2), and I also want the second one.

But I need to be careful, because the best offer is NOT the one where the difference between the original price and the offer is bigger.
For example, if product A costs $1000, and now it is for $900, and the product B was $5 and now is for $1, I have this:

```
A-> $1000 - $900 = $100
B-> $5 - $1 = $4
```

So, the price diference in the product A is bigger, but the product B has the best offer!
How can I do that?

Comment: could you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide how to do that, but a reasonable approach is to use the amount of the discount.  For $1000 --> $900 that is 10%; for $5 --> $1 it is 80%.

```
SELECT p.id, p.descricao, p_s.preco as antigo, pr.preco as novo
FROM produtos_supermercados p_s JOIN
     produtos p
     ON(p_s.id_produto = p.id) JOIN
     promocoes pr
     ON(pr.id_produto = p.id)
ORDER BY pr.preco / p_s.preco desc;
```